# issue with php mysql update

Tags: php, mysql

why I can not update my table?

```
$conn = $this->connectDB();
$where = " WHERE ".$tkey." = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($tvalue))."'" ;
$q = $key." = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($value))."'";
echo $sql = "UPDATE ".$table." SET ".$q.$where;

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$this->disconnectDB($conn);
```

it return "Record updated successfully" but when I check DB no change.

echo of `$sql`:

> UPDATE Articls SET state = '0' WHERE url =
>   'http:/www.example.com/en/news/206698'

call function:

```
updateDB('state',0,'url','http:/www.example.com/en/news/206698','Articls');
```

Comment: try to change it `UPDATE Articls SET state = '0' WHERE url LIKE 'http:/www.example.com/en/news/206698'`. execute directly in db and check updation happening or not?

Comment: no success - same error

Comment: I asked it to run in db table not through php code

Comment: Are you sure that nothing changes into db ? Try to use mysqli_affected_rows after the query to see if there is any row affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement executed successfully, but no records will be updated if none of them matches the `WHERE` clause of the statement. Use [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) to check if any rows were updated.

Hint: You have only one slash after `http:` in the url. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the cause.. Is your state column an integer?

You are showing your trying to set the 'state' column to a string with the value 0:

```
UPDATE Articls SET state = '0' WHERE url = 'http:/www.example.com/en/news/206698'
```

If your 'state' column is an integer, you shouldn't wrap the value in quotes.

It should be:

```
UPDATE Articls SET state = 0 WHERE url = 'http:/www.example.com/en/news/206698'
```

PS: You have a typo in the name of your table. It should be "Articles".